# How to calculate the time left between now and a date in the future

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have a start date and end date during a week, and I have to subtract each day that passes during the week. As each day goes by I want to display 6 days left, 5 days left, etc.

I tried this:

```
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

if (endDate == startDate)
{
    // do something
}
```

But it's not working.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to accomplish here. Are you trying to show the days remaining somewhere? Where is `startDate` defined? What do you mean when you say *"I have to subtract each day during the week"*? Subtract from *what*? Please define better what you mean by *"it's not working"*.

Comment: @Rufus L yes, then I trying to show the remaining days through Viewbag. Startdate will get from my db. I mean I have total seven days from start to end day, and need subtract one day until seven days is not spent. Sorry if i was unconvincing.

Comment: If you start with 6 days, it's a simple integer. You subtract 1 from an integer each day. There is no DateTime involved in your description.

Comment: yes, but for further logic it should be date time, thanks

Comment: So what you're trying to do isn't calculating how many days are left until a specific date in the future, for example you're **not** asking for a solution to how many days are left from today to Sunday, right?

Comment: @Aydin yes exactly, I`m trying in this way.

Comment: Ok so you are trying to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the user is asking for time left between now and a specific date.

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2019, 12, 25);
TimeSpan timeLeft = dateTime - DateTime.Now; // At time of posting, it is 18/12/2019

Console.WriteLine($"{timeLeft.Days} days left");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are always subtracting from DateTime.Now (`DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);`)

```
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Today;
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
do
{
    enddate = enddate.AddDays(-1);
}while(enddate>=startdate);
```

Comment: You declare `endDate` twice

Comment: @dcg yeah i made a mistake as i copied from my first line.

Comment: @Jawad he says that end date and start date is given, I'm just showing the error part

Comment: ahhhhhhhhh, the loop starts at the end date, and it ends at the start date. I get it, but it's confusing :)